# Как увязать два запроса в БД

Tags: php, mysql

подскажите пожалуйста как в коде прописать два запроса в БД
Таблица, пользователи и таблица платеж, в отдельности запросы работают, а вместе - запись идет, обновление нет.

```
if(isset($_POST['label']))
        mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO plateg (summa, id_user, typ, data, opis)  VALUES ('".$_POST['amount']."', '".$_POST['label']."', 1, NOW(), 'Пополнение кошелька через Яндекс.Деньги')");
        return true;   

if(isset($_POST['amount']))
$query_update_user=mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE user SET summa=summa+".$_POST['amount']." WHERE id_user='".$_POST['label']."'"); 

include('../../balans.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

По-умолчанию, [оператор if](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.if.php), если условие истинно, выполняет только одну инструкцию, а для множества инструкций надо заключать их в фигурные скобки. Отступы делаются для человека, чтобы удобнее было читать.

`return true;` в приведенном коде выполняется безусловно и сразу приводит к завершению работы функции. Т.е. все, что ниже этой строчки - никогда не выполнится. Надо вспомнить - зачем эта строчка была нужна и что-то с ней сделать: либо удалить, либо перенести туда, куда надо.

Comment: Спасибо, учу дальше.